# I need help solving a ODE converting it to system of linear different equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'''+4y''+5y'+2y=10cos(t)$

Where it is subject to a condition

$y''(0)=3, y'(0)=0, y(0)=0$

Ok I'm having a very hard time to solving this b/c if one is going to solve using system of linear different equations don't we need a forcing term. I have solved for the Yc which is

$Y_c=c_1v_1e^{-t}+c_2(v_1+v_2t)e^{-t}+c_3v_3e^{-2t} $

and my lambda= -1,-1,-2

and my vectors are $v_1=[1,-1,1] v_2=[1,0,-1] v_3=[1,-2,4]$

but for the Yp I don't know how solve without forcing terms.

Am I doing something wrong?

Help would be much appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Is that $y(0) = 0$?

Comment: yes sorry! y(0)=0

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381528/express-differential-equations-as-system-of-first-order-equations/381538#381538).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will guide you through hints and see if you can fill in the blanks using two methods and recommend a third.

**Method 1 (Complimentary and Particular Solution)**

For the complementary solution, we have:

$m^3 + 4m^2 + 5 m = 2 = 0 \rightarrow m_1 = -1, m_2 = -1, m_3 = -2$

This gives us a complimentary solution (when using the ICs) of:

$$y_c =  3 e^{-t} (t-1) + 3 e^{-2 t}$$

To find the particular solution, we guess at a solution in the form of:

$$y_p = a \cos t + b \sin t$$

Differentiate and substitute into ODE and solve for constants.

You should end up with:

$$y(t) = e^{-2 t} \left(-2 e^t (t-1)+2 e^{2 t} \sin t-1\right)-\cos t $$

**Method 2 (Matrix DEQ)**

We need to rewrite the system as a set of first order equations, so we let $x_1=y$ and have:

- $x_1' = y' = x_2$
- $x_2' = y'' = x_3$
- $x_3' = y''' = -4y'' - 5y' -2y + 10 \cos t = -4x_3 - 5x_2 -2x_1 + 10 \cos t$

Our initial conditions are now expressed as $x_1(0) = 0, x_2(0) = 0, x_3(0) = 3$. Please make a note that we have time $t_0 = 0$ as we need that for later.

Now, we have a system of three equations and we can rewrite it using matrix equations as:

$$x'(t) = Ax(t) + F(t), \text{with IC vector}~~ C$$

To solve this matrix equation with forcing function we have:

$$\tag 1 \displaystyle x(t) = e^{At}C + \int_{t_0}^{t} e^{A(t-s)}F(s)~ds$$

So, we have:

$$\tag 2 x'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}x_1'(t)\\x_2'(t)\\x_3'(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\ -2 & -5 & -4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1(t)\\x_2(t)\\x_3(t) \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\ 10\cos t \end{bmatrix}, C = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\3 \end{bmatrix}, t_0 = 0$$

We have a generalized eigenvector for $v_3$ due to eigenvalue with multiplicity of two. We have eigenvalues/eigenvectors as (I changed the order you used, but it does not matter):

- $\lambda_1 = -2, ~v_1 = (1, -2, 4)$
- $\lambda_2 = -1, ~v_2 = (1, -1, 1)$
- $\lambda_3 = -1, ~v_3 = (2, -1, 0)$

Let me kick start you, to solve $(2)$, from $(1)$, we get:

$$e^{At}C = \begin{bmatrix}3 e^{-t} (t-1)+3 e^{-2 t}\\-3 e^{-t} (t-2)-6 e^{-2 t}\\3 e^{-t} (t-3)+12 e^{-2 t} \end{bmatrix}$$

Next do the integral (it is not bad), so see if you can do the others from this since you know the result.

**Method 3: Variation of Parameters w/Greene's Function**

This method is very useful because it makes it very easy to change the forcing function with little work.

Give it a go if you are bored!

Comment: I'm liking your approach (+).

Comment: Thanks so much for your input @Amzoti

Comment: I do understand how to solve this using that method, but I need to solve this problem using the matrix approach. Sorry for the bad grammar! I'm embarrassed.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know you could solve for the forcing term, but I still don't understand how you did that. Is that some kind of formula that I should remember?

Comment: @bob: Yes, it is very useful, but there are a lot of moving parts to this method, so Method 1 is preferred, maybe followed by Variation of Parameters, followed by this method and others! You can see these approaches in books on Control Theory for example.

Comment: @Amzoti Your are soo awesome! You have save me so much time and suffering. I have done and redone this problem for hours. Googling and looking at my book for any clue on what to do. Thank You Much!

Comment: @bob: There are many wonderful mathematicians on MSE, but you are too kind, thank you. You might want to search for notes on Linear-Time-Invariant (LTI) systems for more examples. For example, see the section on [*Forced-Input-Case*](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/~roy/classnotes/210a/ECE210a_lecture17_small.pdf) in these notes (so seek out others now that you know what to look for). Lastly, are you sure that weren't supposed to use Variation of Parameters as that is likely in your book? Regards

Comment: Awesome feedback! That's what puts a smile on one's face, when all is said and done.

Comment: @amWhy: I always have your back! :-)

Comment: "back at you"  :^)

Comment: Thank you amWhy and Amzoti for understanding I am an engineering student with dyslexia. So I do get very embarrassed with my writing.

Comment: Actually (not that it really matters here), since the forcing term is the solution of a linear, time invariant second order ODE, you could write the entire system as a fifth order autonomous linear time invariant ODE (with appropriate initial condition).

Comment: @copper.hat: That didn't even cross my mind, but now I am thinking about it - nice observation! Regards

Comment: Not mine, it was a clever observation from a colleague of mine (Tzyh-Lih Wuu, almost three decades ago) when we were studying under the same advisor. He used it so he could simulate/optimize a LTI system for a certain class of inputs just using a routine that computed the matrix exponential.

Comment: @copper.hat: Do you know if there is a source for solving the problem using this approach? It would be nice to look at! Regards

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if it was ever published as a paper. It might be in "On the design of stabilizing compensators via semi-infinite optimization" with E. Polak, IEEE Automatic Control, Vol.34, Issue 2 (I am just pulling this from the web). Definitely in his thesis at Berkeley.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks for the references, I will see if I can get them. Regards

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't answer your question, the point of this problem was to use matrices. Also could I solve this using  undetermined coefficients?

Comment: @bob: Undetermined Coefficients is really the first method we did, so yes, that works.

Comment: @Amzoti: So let say I solve using first method, then after finding the Coefficients plug them into the matrices form. Can I do this?

Comment: @bob: No, because that is not using the methods as intended and they get you to the same place. All three methods are standalone. Places where you use methods like that are numerical methods in order to jump start the initial estimates like predictor-corrector methods.

Comment: Thank you for your input yet again. @Amzoti

Comment: @bob: You are very welcome. Regards

Comment: Here is a medal for you Amzoti, $\LARGE{\maltese}$.

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you my friend!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Thank you, those take a long time to write up! Regards