# Consider the following differential equation$ y'' + 5y' + 4y = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

a) Determine a system of equations $x' = Ax$ that is equivalent to the differential equation.

b) Suppose that $y_1, y_2$ form a fundamental set of solutions for the differential equation,
and $x(1), x(2)$ form a fundamental set of solutions for the equivalent system. Show that
$$W[y_1, y_2](t) = k W[x(1), x(2)](t)$$ for some $k$ in $R$.
(Hint. You don't have to solve for $y_1, y_2$ or $x(1), x(2)$, but you can if you want to)

Comment: For $(a)$ see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381528/express-differential-equations-as-system-of-first-order-equations/381538#381538).

Comment: thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part a): The easiest way is to let $x_1 = y, x_2 = y'$. Then $x_1' = x_2$ and
$x_2' = -5 x_2 -4 x_1$. The $A$ matrix is straightforward to compute from these equations.

Part b): Show that $t \mapsto y_1(t)y_2'(t)-y_1'(t)y_2(t)$ and $t \mapsto x_1(t)x_2'(t)-x_1'(t)x_2(t)$ satisfy the same differential equation.