# Converting nth order ODE with RHS into system of 1st order ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I looked at these two questions, but they weren't directly relevant to my specific question:

[How to reduce higher order linear ODE to a system of first order ODE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501745/how-to-reduce-higher-order-linear-ode-to-a-system-of-first-order-ode)

[Express differential equations as system of first order equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381528/express-differential-equations-as-system-of-first-order-equations)

So, let's say for something like this:
y''' + 2y'' - y' - 2y = 0

x1 = y, x2 = y', x3 = y''
x1' = y' = x2
x2' = y'' = x3
x3' = y''' = 2y + y' - 2y'' = 2x1 + 2x2 - 2x3

I know this would eventually turn into the matrix:

A = [0 1 0, 0 0 1, 2 1 -2]

and I know how to continue on from there.

But let's say the original equation had something on it's left hand side, like for example:

y''' + 2y'' - y' - 2y = e^t

I understand that the setting up of the x1,x2,x2, etc. would be the same, but how would I set up the matrix A? Because for the third row, it would be: 2x1 + 2x2 - 2x3 + e^t. Where would I place the e^t in the matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is always the same. But you don't always have a linear system, so you won't always get a matrix that can complete describe the right-hand side.

Define $y_1 = y$. Define $y_2 = y'$. And so forth. What we want to do is create a system of the form

$$\dot{\mathbf{y}} = \mathbf{f}(t,\mathbf{y}).$$

In this case, what we end up with is

$$\begin{align*}
y_1' &= y_2 \\
y_2' &= y_3 \\
y_3' &= e^t + 2y_1 + y_2-2y_3
\end{align*}$$

This can be written in vector form as

$$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ e^t\end{pmatrix}.$$